# Usage of current_user_can()

Tags: capabilities

I have a custom post type `company`, which has its own custom set of capabilities, including `read_company`, `edit_companies`, `publish_companies`, and `delete_companies`.

In order to implement a role-based access, I added the following code on top of a page.

```
<?php
/**
 * Permission check
 */

 $required_permission = 'read_company';
 if( !current_user_can( $required_permission ) ) {
    echo 'You do not have permission to access this resource.';
    exit;
 }
?>
```

However, it's not working. Even if I log-in with a user account that has read_company capability, it always says 'You do not have permission to access this resource.'

I looked into the current_user object to make sure the user has this capability, and it does have. Below is the var_dump result:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

var_dump( $current_user );

object(WP_User)#114 (7) { 
    ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#131 (12) { 
        ["ID"]=> string(2) "17" 
        ["user_login"]=> string(13) "test@test.com" 
        ["user_pass"]=> string(34) "$P$Bs1fndnVSAQS.41doI28wqQ9/RoGmk0" 
        ["user_nicename"]=> string(12) "testtest-com"
        ["user_email"]=> string(13) "test@test.com" 
        ["user_status"]=> string(1) "0"
        ["display_name"]=> string(9) "User Test" 
    } 
    ["ID"]=> int(17) 
    ["caps"]=> array(2) { 
        ["subscriber"]=> bool(true) 
        ["employee"]=> bool(true) 
    } 
    ["cap_key"]=> string(15) "wp_capabilities" 
    ["roles"]=> array(1) { [1]=> string(8) "employee" } 
    ["allcaps"]=> array(8) { 
        ["read_company"]=> bool(true) 
        ["read_private_companies"]=> bool(true)
        ["read_customer"]=> bool(true)
        ["read_private_customers"]=> bool(true) 
        ["read_vendor"]=> bool(true)
        ["read_private_vendors"]=> bool(true)
        ["subscriber"]=> bool(true)
        ["employee"]=> bool(true) 
    } 
    ["filter"]=> NULL }
```

Yes, it does have `read_company` capability, but my permission check code says it doesn't.

Anyone has any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is the check placed? It is possible that it runs before `init`?

Comment: Hi G.M., the check code is placed at the top of page.php and single.php, and thus I am sure the check code runs after init.